# Check if databasefield contains value from imploded variable

Tags: php, mysql, explode, implode

```
$users = explode(",", $particiTemp);
                foreach($users as $user) {
                    echo "$user";
                }

                $checkSQL = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM this WHERE x>'$y' && v<'$z' &&  user IN ($particiTemp)");
                while($checkData = mysql_fetch_array($checkSQL)){

                }
```

I´m kinda stuck right here...

I want to check if $particiTemp (for example: `$particiTemp = "2,23,11,4,"`) is in the field `$checkData[user] ($checkData[user] = "5,22,11,23";)`.

I tried to explode both and tried `mysql IN` but I don´t know how to check if the field `$checkData[user]` CONTAINS one of the imploded `$particiTemp`

Comment: This is an example of bad database design. Store your checkData in a separate table, with userID and data as colums. One data value in each row. Then the queries become very simple and easy to maintain.

Comment: I don't entirely get your question. Is this MySQL or PHP related? Can you get the data from the database as desired and need to know how to check the variables or do you want some suggestions on your MySQL statement? By the way, mysql_* functions are soooo 2000-late. Consider using MySQLi or PDO

Comment: I don´t know if i can check this with mysql. That´s why i tried it in PHP, too. These "particitemp" can contain up to 20 users (id) and its the same field as $checkData[user], just to check if it already exists with that user in it...

Comment: Not sure if I understood what you want to achieve (if you can give more details on that, I might give you more helpful suggestions), but the way I understand it, you are approaching this far too complicated than necessary. Check the comment of Jelle

Comment: Thanks for the help. I´ll get it done somehow...maybe it´s really simple but i can´t get it done right now...anyway thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"In" clause need values as '2','23','11','4' instead of "2,23,11,4,"

so manipulate your array for result.

```
$innval = '';
foreach($users as $user) {
  if($user != '')
    $innval .= "'".$user."',";
}
$innval = substr($innval,0,-1);  // to remove last extra ,
```

and now use this $innval variable in your query to get result

```
$checkSQL = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM this WHERE x>'$y' && v<'$z' &&  user 
IN ($innval)");
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Idea: explode array to check, for each a mysql_query with INSTR.

Should work, trying it now.